# Storing an unsigned char in register (x86 assembly)

Tags: c, x86, inline-assembly

I am writing a function that has 3 parameters passed to it.

```
void function(unsigned char* one, int two, unsigned char three) {
    __asm 
    {
            mov eax, one
            mov ebx, two
            mov ecx, three //Having issues storing this variable in a register
```

But I get a compile error "operand size conflict" for the "three". The other two store just fine. I am trying to figure out why... it compiles if I use `lea ecx, three`. However the value stored is wrong.

Side question. Am I understanding correctly that the first parameter is passing me a memory location for that variable?

Thanks!

Comment: PRobably because `mov <32 bit register>, <8 bit memory reference>` isn't a valid instruction. (I'm not sure if it actually is, but it appears not)

Comment: Googling "operand size conflict" gives you the answer, or at least explains why you're getting the error without even clicking on a search result. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most x86 instructions require all the arguments to be the *same size*. In this case, `three` is an 8-bit argument so use an `mov` with an 8-bit destination to load it, like `mov cl, three`.

There are a few `mov`-like instructions which allow *extending* from a smaller source to a larger destination. For example, you can use `movzx ecx, three` (move with zero-extension) to load the byte into `ecx` and zero the top three bytes.

Comment: This does work. but why wouldnt something like `mov ecx, byte ptr [three]` work?

Comment: There is no such instruction in x86. `mov` and most other instructions require the source and destination to be the same size. You can use `movzx ecx, three` to load the byte into `ecx` and zero the top three bytes.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to not move parameters into registers explicitly by "mov" instructions, because if you have compiled your project to "Register" calling convention, then "one", "two" and "three" are just the aliases for the registers and you may overwrite the data that you need, you just insert unnecessary "mov" instructions into your code. Just take into consideration what parameter comes in what register and use these parameters immediately. But be careful with the parameters that have size less then the register size. Higher bits may be undefined (trashed).

It depends on the particular calling convention, but, most probable, for a 32-bit register calling convention, a call passes first parameter in EAX, second in EDX, third in ECX. The result is returned in EAX (32-bit) or EAX:EDX pair (64-bit). See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Program_Control#Register_Convention for more detail.

In your case, the "unsigned char three" immediately comes in ECX, "two" in EDX and "one" in EAX, you need not to do any moves, buts since "three" is just a char (8 bits) and ECX is dword (32 bits), the bits 8-31 of ECX may contain trash. You should not rely on the assumption that these bits are zero.

For a 64-bit calling convention, first parameter is passed in RCX, second - RDX, third R8, fourth - R9, and the result is returned in RAX. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx for more information for 64-bit.